# Using javascript self.location and regular expression to create a "Next Page" button

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with an extremely simple feature. It is a "Next Page" button that simple only returns "undefined" whatever I do.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#nextButton').click(function() {
            rgx = /page=(\d+)/g;
            page = rgx.exec(self.location)[1];
            var pageNow = parseInt(page);
            var pageNext = pageNow + 1;
            if (page >= 1) {
                var url = self.location;
                self.location = url.replace('&page=' + pageNow, '&page=' + pageNext);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<body>
<button id="nextButton">Next</button>
</body>
```

The button currently redirects to a page with an undefined url ending.

Apologize in advance for taking up your time with basic questions.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Where does the problem come from? Put some `alert()` here and there to see what's happening.

Comment: I have alerted self.location, url, pageNow, and pageNext. Everything seems fine until I do the final line with url.replace...

Comment: Try `window.location.replace(url.replace(...))` instead of `self.location = url.replace(...)`.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same now. If the url is http://www.domain.com/search?query=google&page=1 I am redirected to http://www.domain.com/undefined. I want to be redirected to http://www.domain.com/search?query=google&page=2

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UqtRF/): it should work...

Comment: `self.location` is an object. Use `self.location.href` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `self.location` is a location object. Try to use `self.location.href` instead.

```
    if (page >= 1) {
        var url = self.location.href;
        self.location.href = url.replace('&page=' + pageNow, '&page=' + pageNext);
    }
```